# Reactjs + MaterialUI: SelectField event handling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build my website by mean of ReactJS and [MaterialUI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/usage). Specifically, I am trying to build a form with a [`SelectField`](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field). It looked very easy, but then I got stuck as I tried to make it a controlled component. I just would like that whenever the user selects an item in the drop down list, that item becomes the `value` of the select field.

The rendered select field is like this (`websites` is an array of strings):

```
<SelectField floatingLabelText="Website" onChange={(evt) => this.websiteDidChange(evt)} value={this.state.website} >
            {websites.map(function(w, index){
              return  <MenuItem key={index} label={w} value={w}>{w}</MenuItem>;
            })}
</SelectField>
```

And the function where I handle the `onChange` event is:

```
  websiteDidChange(evt) {
    this.setState({
      website: evt.target.value
    });
  }
```

Unofrtunately, when I select an item, `evt.target.value` results undefined. Can anyone see what am I missing? Should I use another property from the event? I couldn't really figure it out from the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself: apperently the `onChange` callback receives two arguments: the event and the newly selected index. So I updated the code like below and it works:

```
websiteDidChange(newIndex) {
  this.setState({
    website: websites[newIndex]
  });
}

...

<SelectField floatingLabelText="Website" onChange={(evt, newIndex) => this.websiteDidChange(newIndex)} value={this.state.website} >
            {websites.map(function(w, index){
              return  <MenuItem key={index} label={w} value={w}>{w}</MenuItem>;
            })}
</SelectField>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the onChange function receives the selected value as the third argument, so you could have used that directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the third event is the payload value according to the docs:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field

> Callback function fired when a menu item is selected.
>
> Signature: function(event: object, key: number, payload: any) => void
>   event: TouchTap event targeting the menu item that was selected. key:
>   The index of the selected menu item, or undefined if multiple is true.
>   payload: If multiple is true, the menu's value array with either the
>   menu item's value added (if it wasn't already selected) or omitted (if
>   it was already selected). Otherwise, the value of the menu item.

Example:

```
<SelectField
            value={this.props.someValue}
            onChange={(evt, key, payload)=>console.log(payload)}
        >
```